I am trying to understand why is there a "const char *s;" on the 2nd line in the body of the function memmove from string.c
Looking at the code from string.c for memmove I can see that there is a const char *s; and that s is later assigned the value of src; I was wondering, why didn't the author just skip the const char *s; line and why didn't they use src directly? I understand the reason for tmp, since the function has to return dest and we do not want to lose it! :)
void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count)
{
    char *tmp;
    const char *s;

    if (dest <= src) {
        tmp = dest;
        s = src;
        while (count--)
            *tmp++ = *s++;
    } else {
        tmp = dest;
        tmp += count;
        s = src;
        s += count;
        while (count--)
            *--tmp = *--s;
    }
    return dest;
}


The real question is why doesn'ts get initialized to src before the if.

if (dest <= src) Is comparing two void* variables properly defined, to start with?

@Gerhardh No, it's not.  Doubly so because there's no guarantee that dest and src refer to the same object.  So the pointer comparison isn't defined whether they're void * pointers or anything else.  But as this is part of the implementation, those rules don't really apply.

@WilliamPursell It's probably pre-C99 code where all variables had to be declared up front without initialization.  Annoyingly. s is used for src and tmp is used for dest.  Huh?

You can't perform pointer arithmetic on a const void* that's why.
(Some compilers support void* arithmetic as a non-standard extension.)

I would use unsigned char instead

I personally would use casting at each iteration? Like so: *(char *)dest = *(char *)src; Is this more expensive in terms of number of operations performed?

@Atti Casts typically don't cause any run-time overhead. But *(char*)src += count; is far less readable code than what you have.

@Atti you can't legally do src++ with a void* as well.

@Gerhardh I see, however, I have just done dest++; src++; after that line with casting and it works fine? No errors and no warnings? I checked sizeof(void) and it returns 1. Which means sizeof(void) == sizeof(char) ? Or, is this only true for Ubuntu Linux and may not be true for all other distros and OSes?

@Atti If sizeof(void) returns 1, your compiler has one of the non-standard extensions Lundin mentioned. You could see what is says if you add the compiler option -pedantic-errors (which makes it more strict).

@Atti Please note that gcc isn't a standard C compiler by default. It's a "GNU C language" compiler, which is an extension/variation of C. Try again, compiling with -std=c17 -pedantic-errors. That tells gcc "can you be a C compiler instead please?"

(Notably, there is no requirement that internals of the C standard libs has to be written in standard C though. They don't even have to be written in C.)

Thank you all! :) I understand now! :) All is clear, void pointer is not iterable unless casted to a type first.


why didn't the author just skip the const char *s; line and why didn't they use src directly?

In *tmp++, you step the address held by tmp one sizeof *tmp byte(s) forward in memory. Since tmp is a char* it will step sizeof(char) (1) byte forward.
The problem with void is that it doesn't have a size, so sizeof *src (sizeof(void)) doesn't make sense and will be rejected by most compilers.
